# invalid syntax when Passing "args": "..." in VSCode with Pythonq

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am following directions below when passing a command line argument to a python script I'm debugging

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28059

Normally I would launch the script with a dir argument, which doesn't need the `dir` prefix

For example: `python script.py c:\output_folder` launches the script and sets `c:\output_folder` as the dir variable

So following direction online, I have the following in the `launch.json` file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "preLaunchTask": "shellCommand",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["c:\\output_folder"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When trying to debug the python file in VS Code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\portablepython\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 429, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 266, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 236, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "C:\code\.vscode\launch.json", line 2
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's clearly giving an error on `launch.json` so I know its not in the python scripts

Why doesn't the `"args"` line work in `launch.json` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `"program": "${file}"` set it means the debugger will launch the file you currently you have open. Based on the traceback it appears you're launching the debugger with `launch.json` open as your current file. Switch to the file you want to debug and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Question - Why are you assuming it's the "args" key that's causing the issue? The very last line in the traceback gives you a pretty clear description of what the problem is, and even prints out the line causing the error with a caret pointing to the position in the line where the error occurred. While I'm not super familiar with vscode, the JSON spec does not define a comment syntax. My guess is that the application is trying to parse the line

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
```

as JSON. And since it is not valid JSON, it's throwing an error. If so, the two lines directly below that one will present the same problem.